# display all dates given start and end date

Tags: tcl

My following code fetches 2 dates

```
foreach records $get_times {
        lassign $records start_date stop_date
        puts [clock format [clock scan $start_date] \
            -format {%d %b}]
        puts [clock format [clock scan $stop_date] \
            -format {%d %b}]
}
```

Is there a way I can display all the dates between the start_tdate and stop_date.
Something like:

```
puts "<tr><td>the $start_date</td>the next Date</td><td>....</td><td>the $stop_date</td>"
```

Comment: What version of Tcl are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clock scan`'s ability to use "english" timeframes to get what you're looking for. For example:

```
set start_ts [clock scan $start_date]
set end_ts [clock scan $stop_date]
for {set current $start_ts} {$current < $end_ts} {set current [clock scan "+1 day" -base $current} {
    puts [clock format $current -format {%d %b}]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean you want to print each day between start_date and stop_date, I would use **clock add** in a while loop.

```
set start_date [clock scan {2012-04-20 00:00:00} -format {%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}]
set stop_date [clock scan {2012-04-24 00:00:00}  -format {%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}]
while {$start_date<$stop_date} {
  set start_date [clock add $start_date 1 day]
  puts $start_date
}
```

Comment: Probably better to add `1 day` for daylight savings transition days.

Comment: In fact, necessary: midnight on November 4 Eastern time + 24 hours = 11pm on November 4

Comment: @glennjackman good point! I wasn't too worried about the time increment as the original poster didn't even specify what interval they wanted